# Passing on responsibilty

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Is there a word which means passing on the query to someone or a team with more knowledge on the specific subject?

For example your response may be

> Unfortunately I do not know the solution so I have _____ to the relevant team.

Comment: ***pass the buck***

Comment: @DanBron Pass the buck would imply it was done to blame the other team.  In this case, it's a work related issue and no blame is intended. I wouldn't agree that Pass the buck would be correct in this context.

Comment: @Karlomanio Yes, completely agreed. That said, "pass-the-buck" can be used in a self-effacing way, similar to "No, wait, I tell a lie" when you've just made an erroneous statement and realized it a moment later.

Answer (score 5):

to **[refer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refer)** *transitive verb*

2a : to send or direct for treatment, aid, information, or decision

> I have referred it to the relevant team.